# Is it possible to give one general definition of the normal ordering symbol?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

In Quantum Field Theory one usually defines the Normal Ordering Symbol by means of examples and a description of its action: the normal ordering $N$ applied to one expression will be the expression itself if it doesn't contain creation/annihilation operators, or it will move all creation operators to the left of the annihilation operators if it contains those.

So for example:

$$N(a_p a_q^\dagger a_k)=a_q^\dagger a_p a_k$$

$$N\left(\int \dfrac{d^3 k d^3q}{(2\pi)^6\sqrt{4\omega_k\omega_q}}a_k a_q^\dagger\right)=\int \dfrac{d^3k d^3q}{(2\pi)^6 \sqrt{4\omega_k\omega_q}}a_q^\dagger a_k$$

and so forth.

The problem is: with the description and examples it is fairly easy to compute normal orderings.

My problem is that I find it difficult to handle it involving general cases for example when trying to prove things like Wick's theorem.

Some problems are: it is too general: it can act on just a product, act on an integral over operators, etc. Second, I can't see a good notation to define the general case.

I mean: I *think* that handling products of arbitrarily many creation/annihilation operators is enough, because $N$ should  commute with the integral and be extended by linearity. But I don't know if just stating this is rigorous enough, or if we would need to derive these properties from a more general definition.

Anyway, even in products, I don't seem to find a good notation to express

$$N(A_1\dots A_n)$$

considering that $A_i$ can be either $a_{p_i}^\dagger$ or $a_{p_i}$.

So how can one define correctly the normal ordering symbol $ N$ and provide a nice notation to handle its general case?